# Xcode can't connect any objects to ViewControllers

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have multiple storyboards and ViewControllers and I am unable to connect any objects. I get the "Can't find any information about class" error message.

I have done the following:

- Deleted derived data.
- Removed reference to all files and added them back.
- Verified target membership
- Restarted my machine.
- Cleaned the project.

I also added the code first "@IBOutlet weak var Button: UIButton?"
But no circle appeared on the left next to the code where it would be empty if no connection was made and opaque if there was a connection.

No circle here.

[image]

What is happening here? It seems as if there is nothing I haven't tried from previous answers to similar problems.

I just realised that the assistant editor has no options for automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the ViewControllers class in the interface builder?
[image]